# django-piston: how to add an entity field to manyToMany related entity fields?

Tags: django, json, django-piston

I have two Entities: Post and Tag, with a ManyToMany relation called 'tagged'

What I need to do, in order to parse json returned on particular client, is output fields by adding a field 'postID' (the pk field of current Post) to Tag related to that post.

So, my output now is:

```
{
    "post": {
        "name": "Dummy name", 
        "pk": 1,
        "tags": [
            {
                "id": 2, 
                "name": "Patio"
            }, 
            {
                "id": 3, 
                "name": "Roof"
            }
        ], 
        "ref": "709230056"
    }
},
```

but it should be:

```
{
    "post": {
        "name": "Dummy name",
        "pk": 1,
        "tags": [
            {
                "id": 2, 
                "name": "Patio",
                "postID": 1,


            }, 
            {
                "id": 3, 
                "name": "Roof"
                "postID": 1,
            }
        ], 
        "ref": "709230056"
    }
},
```

I've alrady tried to play with fields of my Handler but with no success :(

How to do that ?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you do that? You already have the id of the current post. Although, Post and Tags have a many to many relationship.. do you mean that you want to return all of the post id's for each tag?